# Editing a node in a Linked list Part2

Tags: c, linked-list

Related to my previous post [Editing a node in a Linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399169/editing-a-node-in-a-linked-list). I've done the following steps in editing the node:

1. Edit target node data
2. Remove target node
3. Re-insert target node

THE PROBLEM IS THAT I CANNOT RE-INSERT IT AT THE TOP OF THE NODE as follows....

```
std1 90 -> std 2 50 -> std3 20 -> NULL
```

I edited std3 to 100. The result will be like this

```
   std2 50 -> std3 20 -> NULL
```

In short, i cannot put it back on the top node. Re-inserting anywhere other than the top node works fine.

Comment: What doesn't work? Inserted in the wrong place, not inserted, other entries go missing, segmentation fault, ...?

Comment: Breaks if you're inserting a student with the same grade as another. Your while loop in insert_student doesn't execute and so the assignment to prev_std->next will fail as prev_std is still NULL. One of the conditions in insert_student needs to include "=" as well as less-than or greater-than

Comment: I think there is also a problem if the 'head' node itself is being edited: the node removal destroys the list as 'head' is not updated to point to cur->next .

Comment: Before the call to insert_student(), where you do `prev->next = cur->next; ...` - you will need to check if `cur == head` and update head if this is true. In general, it would be helpful if you gave a concrete scenario: existing list content, which student you edit how, and then what the list contains afterwards.

Comment: @Lars thanks. I've overlooked it. Thank you

Comment: why don't just copy memory and forget deleting a node, then create a new one, link to the existing others in the right place and all this mess? ;)

Comment: "linking to the existing others in the right place" was exactly the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have an issue if the head node is a 97%, and you pass a node with a 97%.  You need to say

```
while (curr_std != NULL && to_add->grade <= curr_std->grade){
```

You'll also have an issue if the student you're editing is the first node, because this:

```
while((cur != NULL) && (strcmp(cur->name,temp) != 0)){
```

will evaluate to true, and

```
prev = cur;
```

will never get called, leaving `prev` = null.  Then when you get to

```
prev->next = cur->next;
```

you have a null reference.  You need to explicitly test for adding to the head node; it's its own special case.

```
scanf("%d", &(cur->grade));
if (prev == null) {  // you matched the head
    head = cur->next;
}
else {
    prev->next = cur->next;
}
```

**EDIT**
When you add to the head, in your code, you haven't set the head to point to your new node.  You're returning the old head, which now points to the second node in the list.  Try:

```
while (curr_std != NULL && to_add->grade < curr_std->grade){
    prev_std = curr_std;
    curr_std = curr_std->next;
}

//  if you're adding to the head, you didn't go into the above loop
//  curr_std is still pointing to head in this case
if (curr_std == head) {
    head = to_add
}
else {
    prev_std->next = to_add;
}

to_add->next = curr_std;
return head;
```

Comment: what are the names/grades in the list, and what grade are you changing?  And to what value are you changing it?  See edits above, I spotted one more issue.

Comment: @James B.. my problem is i cannot re-insert it on the top node as exampled above... The rest of the node is working fine.. Except the top node. Thank you

Comment: Yep, that was a third issue that I didn't catch.  Updated my answer.  The first two issues I saw still apply.

Comment: Good catch! I think the question now becomes: how does one find this kind of problem? :)

Comment: Good question!  I think in part it's experience... you do these exercises to learn things like "head nodes are always a special case".  Beyond that, the best way to track down issues in your code is to come up with sets of data, all the possible combinations (adding to the head, adding to the tail, adding to the middle, editing/removing the head, etc.) and asking yourself "what is my code doing at each step?".  When I have a condition that fails, I'll print out my code and write values of every variable for every step in the margin.  Problems like this are a good exercise in critical thinking!